# Не работает скрипт Jquery, не меняется "display: none" на "display: flex"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css3

```js
$(function() {

  $('#top-freeback-online').on('click', function() {
    $('#upblock-freeback').css('display', 'flex');
  });

  $('#upblock-freeback').on('click', function() {
    if (event.target == this) {
      $('#upblock-freeback').css('display', 'none');
    }
  });

});
```

```css
#upblock-freeback {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  background-color: rgba(20, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.top-freeback-online {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #D2392B;
  position: absolute;
  right: 150px;
  padding: 15px 35px;
  border: 2px solid #d2392B;
  font-size: 20px;
  top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="top-freeback-online">Button</div>
<div id="upblock-freeback" style="display: none;">TEXT</div>
```

Нужно что-бы при нажатии на `#top-freeback-online` он появлялся, а при нажатии за это окно закрывалось.

Comment: `.CSS` это не то же самое что `.css`

Comment: Ну и в вашем примере нет `top-freeback-online`, к тому же в CSS это класс, а в js это id. Каша какая-то

Comment: Ещё и у function скобочек не хватает

Comment: А ещё то, что вы хотите сделать по клику, с элементом который имеет св-во  display: none, сделать не получится! Когда присваивается св-во none, элемент выпиливается из вёрстки и становится недоступным. В вашем случае нужен либо таймер, по которому элемент появляется, либо клик по другому элементу. Иными словами, нельзя кликнуть по тому, чего **none!**

Comment: Спасибо, что-то я напортачил.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

Открываем элемент

```
$(document).on("click","#top-freeback-online", function (event) {
event.preventDefault(); 
$(this).addClass("open_active"); 
});
```

где в таблице стилей добавить класс .open_active {display: flex}

Закрываем элемент

```
 $(document).on("click","body", function (event) {
 event.preventDefault(); 
 $("#top-freeback-online").removeClass("open_active"); 
});
```

Comment: Да, вот только по элементу со стартовым св-вом **display: none**, кликнуть не получится.))